# Android class libraries

Tags: java, c++, android, c

Android class libraries are written in C/C++ but java is the preferred language for developing applications.Why not C/C++ instead of java ?

Comment: "Android class libraries are written in C/C++ but java is the preferred language for developing applications." -- false. Android's "class libraries" are written in Java, with some native code via JNI extensions.

Answer (score 5):

If you prefer to develop via C/C++ you may use the NDK. The Android platform is run on the Dalvik Virtual Machine, what you code in java is actually compiled to Dalvik bytecode and run on the VM.

They spent a lot of time developing the facilities to make it fairly painless to make an Android application using a managed language. Some people would consider this an advantage.

Comment: Are Java/Dalvik apps also less subject to variations in hardware than NDK apps? I don't know Android, but I wouldn't be surprised, and if so it would be a second advantage of the VM alongside simply using a managed language.

Comment: you would need to compile your native codes for specific hardware yes, while a pure java android project will run on any android device

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons to choose Java as the platform, but my guess as to the biggest reason why would be to not expose application developers to a slew of porting issues that arise from the sheer number of devices that Android powers. There would be far fewer apps available if every developer had to research every platform nuance for every phone and tablet out there.

Obviously, there are drawbacks, and that's why the [Native Development Kit (NDK)](http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html) exists. The NDK primarily addresses performance issues, but recent additions have included the ability to write an entire app completely in native code.

Answer (score 0):

Java it's used in many application for mobile devices, it is a standard because it is more manageble, even the new languages that are appearing now it's based in java. It is a open language and you can learn it without going to class. Javame is used for mobile devices which incorporates some features of J2EE and adds new classes for the small devices.